# SSRS Report manager SQL 2012: Chart legend

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I make the chart legend thicker? the legend is so thin right now?

thanks

illustrated below. The top one is my current situation and the bottom one is what I would like to get.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to modify that field from within ssrs editor. In the legends property, you have a few parameters in there that can be modified.

Comment: I must be blind. but I tried to find and play around changing the properties but still cannot figure it out. I post the list of all properties available in chart legend in the question. Thanks

Comment: None of them talks about legend Item which is the object I want to change. most of the time Google "legend item" shows only how to change the font size but not the thickness of the legend icon

Comment: Would make sense for the legend "icon" to increase with the size of text. Try changing the type of chart to bars? See if the legend is different for a different chart type.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239321.aspx
To cause the legend text to automatically fit the allocated space, set the AutoFitTextDisabled property to False and set a minimum font size for the MinFontSize property to the lowest font size that you think will be presentable and still allow for legend optimization.

Comment: Correct, if I change it to a bar chart then it will be a nice thick legend icon. But I can't change the chart type. So I will leave the legend icon as is for now

Comment: A line chart will display a line colour sample, same goes for bar graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is; you cannot! Out of the box you cannot change the thickness of the legend item icon.

I have not find a work around yet. Unless maybe just use a static image to display the legend which I won't do.

but if you have a bar chart then the legend will be a nice thick bar. and if you have a line chart then the legend icon will be a nice thin line. No property to change the thickness of it

[image]